# Declarative Web Request Chrome Plugin: how to use regex filter on extension paths?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, browser-extension

I am currently working on a chrome plugin. What i want to do is to redirect traffic from https://localhost/?uri_components=1 to chrome-extension://{extension_id}/?uri_components=1

this is what i have so far:

**part of the manifest.json**

```
"declarative_net_request" : {
"rule_resources" : [{
  "id": "ruleset",
  "enabled": true,
  "path": "rules.json"
}]
```

**rules.json**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "priority": 1,
    "action": { "type": "redirect", "redirect": { "extensionPath": "/popup.html", "regexSubstitution": "1" } },
    "condition": { "regexFilter": "^https://localhost/(.*)", "resourceTypes": ["main_frame"] }
}]
```

redirection works at the moment. The problem is, that i dont know how to pass the url components to the chrome-extension url. For that  you would normally have a regex Substitution as stated here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/

But i could'nt find a way todo this with the extensionPath key. Any Ideas?

Comment: https://crbug.com/1262147

Comment: So what is the solution? working with manifest v2? And use webRequest and Blocking?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I worked around it by using the [`updateDynamicRules`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/declarativeNetRequest/#method-updateDynamicRules) method from the background script. Something like this:

In `manifest.json`, register the background worker:

```
{
    ...,
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    ...,
}
```

And in your `background.js`:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
    chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules({
        removeRuleIds: [1],
        addRules: [
            {
                id: 1,
                priority: 1,
                condition: {
                    regexFilter: "^https://localhost/(.*)",
                    resourceTypes: ["main_frame"],
                },
                action: {
                    type: "redirect",
                    redirect: {
                        regexSubstitution: `chrome-extension://${chrome.runtime.id}/popup.html\\1`,
                    },
                },
            },
        ],
    });
});
```

I hope this helps!